# Declaring time series in Stata

Tags: time, stata, series

I have some panel data with quarterly data in string format (imported from .csv file).

The name of the variable is `datacqrt` and it is in the `format "YYYY"Q"Q"` say `1998Q3`. So I have it from `1966Q1` to `2014Q4` for each of the around 200 categories.

I am following the Stata guide and creating a new variable like this

```
generate time = date(datacqtr,"YQ")
```

but then it creates only missing values.

How do I make Stata understand the variable `datacqrt` is a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `date()` is for creating ***daily*** dates in Stata terms, i.e. days with an origin 0 at 1 January 1960. This is documented at length in (e.g.) `help dates and times` but is even clearer with the synonym `daily()`.

You need the function `quarterly()`, for example:

```
. di %tq quarterly("2015q3", "YQ")
2015q3

. di %3.0f quarterly("2015q3", "YQ")
222
```

In your case you want something like

```
gen qdate = quarterly(datacqrt, "YQ")
```